# Find the area of triangle $\triangle LMN$.

Tags: geometry

> In triangle $\triangle LMN$. $LO$ is median. Also $LO$ is the bisector of angle. If $LO=3\text{ cm}$ and $LM=5\text{ cm}$. Then find the area of triangle $\triangle LMN$.

Now here we will use similarity between $\Delta LMO$ and $\Delta LON$ triangles but I could not proceed further.

Comment: Hint: $3^2+4^2=5^2$

Comment: Make a picture of the problem, that will make it easier!

Comment: yes  i got it now

Comment: the answer will be 12 cm square.3 will be the height and 8 the base of the triangle

Comment: median=bissector line $\implies$ isosceles triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $LO$ is both median and the bisector of $\angle NLM$, $\triangle LMN$ is isosceles and $ LO \perp MN$.

So $MO = NO= \sqrt{5^2-3^2\ }=4$ and area $\triangle LMN = 4\times 3 =12 \text{cm}^2$

---

To see that $\triangle LMN$ is isosceles, consider that $\angle LON = 180°-\angle LOM$. Flip $\triangle LON$ to superimpose $\angle NLO$ and $\angle MLO$. Then the only way to make $|MO|=|NO|$ is to have $\angle LON = \angle LOM =\perp$

Comment: hey LO=3cm so,area will be equal to 12cm2

Comment: @dp1611 thanks, I'm blaming jet-lag for that one.

Answer (score 1):

Its'  isosceles and acute. Because a acute is smaller than a right angle, and there is two of the sides are the same.